# Pass JavaScript variables to Rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing

I'm using rails version 3.2.6 and I'm trying to pass a Javascript variable to another page "Test10". I have the following code in the view:

```
<script>
var message = "hello world!";
</script>

<%= link_to "Go!", Test10_path(), :with => "'message='+ message"  %>
```

The parameter is not passed to Test10. I have the following in the Test10 controller:

```
def Test10
  @hello = params[message]
end
```

Is this the right way to pass a Javascript variable to my rails controller? It is not working. I'd appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "Go!", Test10_path(), :id => "my_link"  %>


<script>
    var message = 'test';
    var url = $('#my_link').attr('href') + '?message=' + message;
    $('#my_link').attr('href', url);
</script>
```

Something like this should work. Although most of the time, it's best to pass params by using forms instead ...

Comment: Thanks @Anthony. That worked! What is the best resource to learn about passing params using forms? And why it is better? Thanks again!!

Comment: If you want to pass values from Javascript, just learn a little bit of jQuery. You also have to learn how to build forms with rails : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: We went through the code and would like to mention that it's simply the submission of a GET request via the URL string.  The URL string is plainly visible on the next page.  Users who are more concerned about security should look elsewhere.  +1 anyway for an obviously successful solution.

Comment: Still serving me well in '16.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. JavaScript and Ruby code execute in completely different contexts, JavaScript on the client and Ruby on the server.

In general, if you want to communicate a value from the client to the server, you need to do so either by posting it back in a form or as part of a query string, or via AJAX.

In your specific example, you'll have to write some JavaScript which selects the anchor tag and appends the contents of the `message` variable to the anchor tag's query string. Something like the following:

```
<script>
  var message = "hello world!";

  // Select your anchor tag
  var link = $('a#my-link');

  // Append your message to the link's href attribute
  link.attr('href', link.attr('href') + "?message=" + message);
</script>
```